# Removal of permanent redirect in Next.js

Tags: next.js

So I added a permanent 308 redirect within my next.config.js as follows:

```
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/foo/',
        destination: '/foo/bar',
        permanent: true,
      }                  
    ]
  },
```

I now need to be able to use both directories:

`/foo/` and `/foo/bar/`

I have removed the redirect from my next.config.js

I've been looking up solutions to no avail, one solution I saw is to redirect `/foo/bar/` back to `/foo/` but this would not work in my scenario since I need to use both locations.

*Another thing I don't understand as well is that `/foo/something-else` is also now redirecting to `/foo/bar/`...*

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Is `/bar` a dynamic / catch-all block? In other words, what does the route look like.